# Bot Emulator Error: POST 400 directline.postActivity

Tags: azure, botframework

I'm trying to run a default EchoBot in the Bot Emulator, and after configuring the endpoint, AppID, and App Password, I get a POST 400 directline.postActivity error.

I'm running Bot Emulator Framework v4.4.1, and the C# v4.4.4 EchoBot sample provided by Microsoft. When I go to build the project in Visual Studio, it outputs to port 3978 on localhost. After entering the endpoint, id, and password into the emulator, it begins to connect. However, the bot doesn't respond to any inputted text. Here is the log from the emulator:

```
[11:05:36]Emulator listening on http://localhost:50550
[11:05:36]ngrok not configured (only needed when connecting to remotely     hosted bots)
[11:05:36]Connecting to bots hosted remotely
[11:05:36]Edit ngrok settings
[11:05:37]
[11:05:37]POSTdirectline.conversationUpdate
[11:05:37]
[11:05:37]POSTdirectline.conversationUpdate
[11:05:37]POST200directline.startConversation
[11:05:40]-> messagehell0
[11:05:40]POST400directline.postActivity
[11:05:43]-> messagefdal
[11:05:43]POST400directline.postActivity

JSON Inspector for startConversation: 
{
  "conversationId": "33eb05b0-8b91-11e9-be8e-6726cb4f7972|livechat",
  "expires_in": 2147483647,
  "streamUrl": "",
  "token": "http://localhost:3978"
}

JSON Inspector for first message:
{
  "channelData": {
    "clientActivityID": "15601791407590.8nf8jwqjc2v"
  },
  "channelId": "emulator",
  "conversation": {
    "id": "33eb05b0-8b91-11e9-be8e-6726cb4f7972|livechat"
   },
  "entities": [
    {
      "requiresBotState": true,
      "supportsListening": true,
      "supportsTts": true,
      "type": "ClientCapabilities"
    }
  ],
  "from": {
    "id": "4866b179-bf7b-460e-8903-bda849861d88",
    "name": "User",
    "role": "user"
  },
  "id": "363766b0-8b91-11e9-be8e-6726cb4f7972",
  "localTimestamp": "2019-06-10T11:05:40-04:00",
  "locale": "en-US",
  "recipient": {
    "id": "33ea6970-8b91-11e9-ab08-9bfc690fe455",
    "name": "Bot",
    "role": "bot"
  },
  "serviceUrl": "http://localhost:50550",
  "text": "hell0",
  "textFormat": "plain",
  "timestamp": "2019-06-10T15:05:40.763Z",
  "type": "message"
}

JSON Inspector for first response:
{
  "channelData": {
    "clientActivityID": "15601791407590.8nf8jwqjc2v"
  },
  "channelId": "webchat",
  "entities": [
    {
      "requiresBotState": true,
      "supportsListening": true,
      "supportsTts": true,
      "type": "ClientCapabilities"
    }
  ],
  "from": {
    "id": "4866b179-bf7b-460e-8903-bda849861d88",
    "name": "User",
    "role": "user"
  },
  "locale": "en-US",
  "text": "hell0",
  "textFormat": "plain",
  "timestamp": "2019-06-10T15:05:40.760Z",
  "type": "message"
}

{
  "error": {
    "code": "ServiceError",
    "message": "response.text is not a function"
  }
}
```

I've tried having a configured endpoint that matches what the emulator states it is configured to, but that only results in an infinite connecting message that doesn't even allow me to input any text to the bot. I've also tried reinstalling the emulator, but that has not changed anything.

**EDITED**

Also, the emulator is configured to bypass ngrok for local addresses, and the local override is set to localhost. These are the default settings, and toggling the bypass option or changing the local override does not solve the problem.

I've tried getting ride of the AppId and AppPassword from the appsettings.json file, both by commenting them out and by leaving them as empty strings, neither of which solved the problem.

I've also uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio, the BotFramework SDK, the template, and the Bot Emulator to see if that would fix anything, but they have not..

One final note, I've tried following the Microsoft BotFramework tutorial about using the emulator, and any attempt yields this result.

**UPDATE**

After reinstalling Bot Framework Emulator v4.4.2, the problem is still there, but there is a new error message:

```
[14:03:32]Emulator listening on http://localhost:61486
[14:03:32]ngrok not configured (only needed when connecting to remotely 
hosted bots)
[14:03:32]Connecting to bots hosted remotely
[14:03:32]Edit ngrok settings
[14:03:32]The bot's Microsoft App Id or Microsoft App Password is 
incorrect.
[14:03:32]POSTdirectline.conversationUpdate
[14:03:32]The bot's Microsoft App Id or Microsoft App Password is 
incorrect.
[14:03:32]POSTdirectline.conversationUpdate
[14:03:32]POST200directline.startConversation
```

I have made sure that they do indeed match, yet I still get this error.

Comment: What is the full endpoint you have configured and are trying? And, do you have the AppId / AppPassword in appSettings.json file? Technically, if you are testing locally-only, you don't need to have the AppId / AppPassword in the project or emulator for it to run. Try removing the values and test.

Comment: The full endpoint is http://localhost:3978/api/messages. The AppId/AppPassword are in the appsettings.json file. If I try testing without inputting the id and password, it outputs only the first 4 lines of the log above, then renders me unable to even submit text to the bot. The same result occurs if I comment out the id and password in the json file.

Comment: Can you try with no id / password in Emulator and, in your appsettings.json file, don't comment out the two lines. Instead, return empty strings.

Comment: No luck on either option.

Comment: They both just give me the first 4 lines of the log, then prevent any text from being inputted.

Comment: Which SDK and version are you running and can you post your code? Also, which version of Emulator are you using?

Comment: I am running v4.4.1 Emulator, v4.4.4 Bot Framework SDK, and am using the default code provided by Microsoft in https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot. The only things I added is an app id and app password, which is currently strongly recommended.

Comment: Are you still struggling with this? Have you tried deleting the project and starting again? The project could have just had an issue during creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you behind a proxy ? I have the exact same problem. I am behind a proxy server . The same code works really well on my mac at home. But on a Windows PC at work it doesnt. I dont know if this helps ! I think the error is generic but the bottomline is that it is unable to fetch a JWTToken from login.microsoftonline.com.

Comment: I am. However, my coworker is also behind that same proxy, and the code appears to run properly on his setup. I will add, the code each of us is using is exactly the same.

Comment: I have tried the following to fix and was unsuccessful. I would appreciate if you could check if any of the same works for you ..   Updated the HTTPS_PROXY environment varibale to point to my proxy server. ( No effect ) . Updated the NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS environment variable to point to the correct CA bundle and again no effect.

Comment: I was finally able to get it to work on Bot Framework Emulator V3.5.36 . I would suggest you check if your co-worker is on a previous version of the emulator. There is something in the new build that is not working correctly. I saw you have raised an issue in Github already. Hopefully you get a response.

Comment: That worked for me as well. However, my co-worker is using the current version of the emulator.

Comment: Can you also check and see if you use a .pac file for your proxy settings?  I doubt if it has something to do with the fact that we use a .pac file. I have tried to disable it but hasnt had any effect. You can look for it in Network Proxy Settings. Maybe you can check if your friend is somehow overriding it or set up differently. I am just shooting ideas! I mention this because of this Github issue that looks very similar to what we are experiencing !   https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/345

Answer (score 2):

Try removing app id and password and ngrok from your solution as well as from the emulator and add only localhost endpoint in the emulator

Comment: Neither of these solutions have worked. I have clarified in the original question additional solutions that have not worked.

Comment: You might have already done this but can you just remove your ngrok settings from your emulator settings also the app id and password.